# Magento 2 - Adding Class to individual Navigation Items on Account Page

Tags: magento2, page, class, account

I need to add a class to each of these navigation items on the Account page.

[image: Account Page Left Sidebar Links]

The file containing the navigation wrapper can be found at (vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\account\navigation.phtml):

```
<div class="block account-nav">
    <div class="title">
        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('My Account')) ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <nav class="account-nav">
            <ul class="nav items">
                <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class for different navigation links, please check below example.

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
  <arguments>
     <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Manage Address</argument>
     <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/address</argument>
     <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">190</argument>
     <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">manage-address</item>
     </argument>
 </arguments>
</block>
```

Hope this will help you. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I have added this to the customer_account.xml but as a referenceBlock. The class is not showing on the front end, please can you advise on this.

Comment: Hve you cleared a cache after updating in xml file?

Comment: Yes I have done. It adds the class now, is there a way for it to target the li rather than adding to the a tag?

Comment: Then you need to change the template for account navigation.

Comment: The account navigation is changed through the customer_account.xml or is it a different template that needs to be altered? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Just simply copy this code:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links"
             template="Magentoexample_Module::account/navigation.phtml" cacheable="false">
            </block>
 </referenceBlock>
```

by creating the below file:

> /app/code/Magentoexample/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

and then create:

> /app/code/Magentoexample/Module/view/frontend/templates/account/navigation.phtml
>    and paste your code like this:

```
<ul class="nav items">
 <li  class="nav item my-custom-class"><a
                href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('customer/account') ?>"><?php echo __('Orders'); ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have added this in as a module following your instructions but I am sure there is more to setting up a module. Can you provide any further instructions as this is not showing up as a module.

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/
Follow this link to create a module. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a class to the **li** tag, and not to the **href** tag, you will need to define a custom template, inside your custom block.

```
class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link implements SortLinkInterface
{
    /* define a custom phtml template */
    protected $_template = 'Mymodule_Customer::my-custom-link.phtml';
```

Now you have to create the file Mymodule/Customer/view/frontend/templates/my-custom-link.phtml

```
<li class="the-class-you-want-to-use">
    <a <?php echo $block->getLinkAttributes() ?>><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel())?></a>
</li>
```